# android browseSupportFragment leanback the items of row overlap suddenly why

Tags: android-tv, leanback

i have an android browseSupportFragment containing list of categories and a row for every category,
the items are displayed well but suddenly i see the items of one row overlapp over each other.
what can be the reason of that issue ??
i am using this leanback

```
 implementation "androidx.leanback:leanback:1.2.0-alpha04"
```

[image: this is the menu having the icons overlapping]

[image: if you focus on the row you can see somes icons behind the icons]

Comment: Can you please provide screen shot with exact issue ? or give some more information.

Comment: @JayRathod i updated my question with images showing the problem of icons in browseSupportFragment i need help to solve this !

Comment: @JayRathod any respnse ?

Comment: it seems to be some Leanback library UI issue or you override one of the properties of library might be.